# Getting the last 30 rows

Tags: sql, mysql

How can you get the last 30 rows (i.e. the last 30 rows to be inserted) into a database using SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT x,y ?
```

An example table:

```
USER: id (auto increment, int, pk), username, email
```

Comment: MySQL?  Syntax would be different in SQL server or some other RDBMS....

Comment: What does the schema look like? Do you have an auto increment id in the table? A 'created' column perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, it has an ID. Sorry, should have made this clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to have some key to go with... is there an auto-incrementing column, then order by THAT column descending...  Ex:

select * from YourTable order by TheAutoIncrementColumn DESC limit 30